# Server-side processing for a php file with 'include' function

Tags: php, include, conditional-statements

can please help me some about php?

I have some files.

```
file1.php   ~1mb
file2.php   ~2mb
file3.php   ~3mb
```

and in **index.php**

index.php

```
<?php
if($state == 1)     include_once('file1.php');
elseif($state == 2) include_once('file1.php');
elseif($state == 3) include_once('file1.php');
?>
```

I want to know server how to proccess index.php?

for eaxmple for `$state == 1`, size of index.php in server is 6mb or 1mb?

Is there any effect on processing speed in server-side?

Comment: 1mb, then file is basically processed top to bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is mistake in your question, but i understand your question.
I think it should be.

```
<?php
  if($state == 1)     include_once('file1.php');
  elseif($state == 2) include_once('file2.php');
  elseif($state == 3) include_once('file3.php');
?>
```

Am i correct?

It will include file only if respected condition is true.

So here the size of index.php will either 1 mb, or 2 mb, or 3 mb. (Depends on which condition is true.) But it will never 6mb.